# checking emptiness for JQuery selector with Underscore

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

following returns empty set:

```
$('.asd')
[]
```

but underscore function return false for emptiness:

```
_.isEmpty($('.asd'))
false
```

what I am understanding wrongly?

Comment: A jQuery object containing no elements still has properties (`context`, `jquery`, `length`, etc.), so it is not "empty" in the sense used by `_.isEmpty()` (or `$.isEmptyObject()` for that matter).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Quoting documentation: `For strings and array-like objects _.isEmpty checks if the length property is 0` (http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty).

Comment: @haim770, jQuery objects are neither strings nor array-like objects.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I assumed so. Yet, when the `length` property is present, why it's still not considered an "array-like object"?

Comment: @haim770, I will have to check Underscore's source code to answer that. I'll be right back :)

Comment: @haim770, well, from the source code, "array-like objects" in the Underscore sense are detected with `toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'`, which will be `false` when applied to a jQuery object.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, that's interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to check whether the element exists or not? You can do this with

```
$('asd').length > 0
```

<s>The jQuery function ($ in your case) returns an empty array if it cannot find anything with the selector specified. Underscore's isEmpty function is for objects, though.</s>

The return value of the jQuery function ($ in your case) is not empty, because, even without elements, it still has properties.

Thanks to Frédéric Hamidi and haim770 for pointing that out.

Comment: Just tested it in Chrome's console. Returns []

Comment: For what it's worth, Firefox's console says `Object[ ]`.

Comment: @sb, It shows `[]` but it still has those extra properties. Try: `var a = $('.bla'); console.log(a.context);`

Comment: Okay, you guys are right: $('asf') instanceof Array returns false. I'll correct it, thank you very much!